# (NOT NATIVELY) Edit records from site.com page?

Tags: visualforce, community, site.com

Has anyone solved this? You can retrieve and submit, but as far as I can tell you can not edit.

I understand this is NOT possible Natively within sites.com. My question is whether anyone has solved this programatically.

Comment: Does the user profile has edit permissions to those objects?

Comment: Yes, full CRUD permissions. The documentation makes no mention of CRUD functionality in site.com forms and data elements, but I would like to know if anyone has found a solution, leveraging JS or other means perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [displaying forms](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_form.htm&language=en_US) for each iteration of the data repeater?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Marty, I have not. Could you explain how this would help to edit records?